# Why am I reading garbage data or getting acces violations?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using Windows Web Services to access a WCF service and it creates a an array of pointers of the results.

I had a similar issue where I was also reading garbage data and I though it might be caused by sendign this data to another function that was causing the pointers to get invalidated but now I'm storing it in a vector reference to try to avoid such issues but the problem persists. I'm not sure what do do anymore.

I also tried using `ListaDeMaterialesBE** lstmat = new ListaDeMaterialesBE*;` but that did not work at all.

Here is the code:

```cpp
void svc_listMaterials(const size_t& idProject, std::vector<ListaDeMaterialesBE>& result) {
    HRESULT hr = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    WS_ERROR* error = NULL;
    WS_HEAP* heap = NULL;
    WS_SERVICE_PROXY* proxy = NULL;

    WS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS address = {};
    const WS_STRING url = WS_STRING_VALUE(L"http://localhost/SIMSE_Service.ServicioEstadistico.svc");
    address.url = url;


    WS_HTTP_BINDING_TEMPLATE templateValue = {};
    ULONG maxMessageSize = 2147483647;
    WS_CHANNEL_PROPERTY channelProperty [ 1 ];
    channelProperty [ 0 ].id = WS_CHANNEL_PROPERTY_MAX_BUFFERED_MESSAGE_SIZE;
    channelProperty [ 0 ].value = &maxMessageSize;
    channelProperty [ 0 ].valueSize = sizeof(maxMessageSize);
    WS_CHANNEL_PROPERTIES channelProperties;
    channelProperties.properties = channelProperty;
    channelProperties.propertyCount = 1;
    templateValue.channelProperties = channelProperties;

    hr = WsCreateError(NULL, 0, &error);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {

    }

    hr = WsCreateHeap(2048, 512, NULL, 0, &heap, error);

    WS_HTTP_BINDING_TEMPLATE templ = {};
    hr = BasicHttpBinding_IServicioEstadistico_CreateServiceProxy(&templateValue, NULL, 0, &proxy, error);

    hr = WsOpenServiceProxy(proxy, &address, NULL, error);


    // The issue starts here
    ListaDeMaterialesBE** lstmat;

    unsigned int rcount;

    hr = BasicHttpBinding_IServicioEstadistico_ListarMaterialesPorProyecto(proxy,
                                                                           idProject,
                                                                           &rcount,
                                                                           &lstmat,
                                                                           heap,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           error);

    // Here is where we seem to be reading garbage data 
    if (rcount > 1 && rcount < 10000) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= rcount; ++i) {
            ListaDeMaterialesBE t = **lstmat;
            result.push_back(t);
            lstmat++;
        }
    }

    if (proxy) {
        WsCloseServiceProxy(proxy, NULL, NULL);
        WsFreeServiceProxy(proxy);
    }

    if (heap) {
        WsFreeHeap(heap);
    }

    if (error) {
        WsFreeError(error);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "errored \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Garbage data is usually a sign of an improperly terminated string. Improper termination can also lead to whatever's using the string seeking off the end of the string and into invalid memory, resulting in an access violation. `if (FAILED(hr)) { }` looks off. I'd expect some error handling and possibly halting the transaction after a failure.

Comment: Whats odd is that 90% of the time I see the data normally with no issues. Just sometimes I will see random characters and even rarer still are access violations(reading strings).

Comment: Add proper error checking for all function calls. Why speculate when you can let the system tell you what is wrong?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I do this and where would I do this?

Comment: Each function you call has a method of indicating error. Describes in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for the error is your wrong use of the returned secondary pointer.

I created a simple example to simulate the problem:

```
#define COUNT 10

void f(int** pp)
{
    *pp = new int[COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        (*pp)[i] = i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int** pp = new int*;
    f(pp);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        cout << **pp;
        pp++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function `f` obtains a secondary pointer, this secondary pointer saves the first address of an array, and then writes it.

Then use your method to traverse the array, it will cause an access exception:

[image]

The reason for the error is that when you use the secondary pointer to perform an auto-increment operation, the distance it moves each time is not the distance of an element you think.

So you should get the first address of the array it saves through the secondary pointer, and then traverse:

```
int** pp = new int*;
f(pp);
auto p = *pp;
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
{
    cout << *p;
    p++;
}
```

Then we can read the correct data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer,this clears up some concepts for me but I could not make it  work. In my case the function returns a triple pointer(ListaDeMaterialesBE***). I tried adapting it but it does not seem to work for me. When I step through with the debugger I see that the first iteration will get the first  struct of the array but it will get null data for the others.Also, I can read the data most of the time but maybe in 30% of the cases I see random characters. My thought is that I'm not telling the program not to overwrite that data,or it may be the library not doing it but I dont know.

Comment: @dominique120 I'm sorry I can't reproduce your problem with the current code, maybe you can share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us solve your problem.